# What encryption is used to encrypt the password

Tags: perl

Hello this is a perl script that will create a file inside a folder in the server
it will ask the user to input username password and email
when the account is created it will be created like that 
username.txt

inside the file will be 
username
password
email

however the password will be encrypted if I put 123456 that will be encrypted to 
cb897EaMgDZy6

I am trying to know what kinda of encryption is used

Comment: what is the script? Please format your code using backticks or CTRL+K

Answer (score 3):

The password wasn't encrypted; it was [hashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) using [`crypt`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt.html).

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say crypt($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]) eq $ARGV[1] ? 1 : 0' 123456 cb897EaMgDZy6
1
```

Note that use of `crypt` must be avoided! It is far too weak to be of any value.